# Why browsing tuple in a loop gives me the first character of my string?

Tags: python, tuples

Could someone explain me this behaviour:

```
REQUIRED_USER_FIELDS = ["email"]
for field in REQUIRED_USER_FIELDS:
    # field = 'email' -> OK for me, expected behaviour

REQUIRED_USER_FIELDS = ("email")
for field in REQUIRED_USER_FIELDS:
    # field = 'e' -> Why???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`("email")` is not a tuple.  It is just a string in parenthesis.

You need to place a comma to make it a tuple:

```
REQUIRED_USER_FIELDS = ("email",)
#                        here--^
```

Otherwise, your for-loop will iterate through the string `"email"` itself.

---

You should remember that it is the *comma* that creates a tuple, not the parenthesis (if any):

```
>>> ("email")
'email'
>>> "email"
'email'
>>> ("email",)
('email',)
>>> "email",
('email',)
>>>
```

The reason why you see parenthesis so often though is that:

1. They make it clearer that you are creating a tuple.
2. You need them in some places, such as when calling a function:

   ```
   >>> def func(arg):
   ...     return arg
   ...
   >>> # This fails because "a", "b" is treated as 2 separate arguments
   >>> func("a", "b")
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
   >>>
   >>> # This works because ("a", "b") is treated as 1 argument (a tuple)
   >>> func(("a", "b"))
   ('a', 'b')
   >>>
   ```

Comment: The parentheses are just often necessary to distinguish between a tuple-comma and other kinds, for example function argument commata.

Comment: @poke - Good note.  I'll mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Tuple which contains just one element is need to be write as below.

```
(something,)
```

You can ensure it by doing:

```
>>> tuple(["email"])
('email',)
```